# Parse GMS Packet with GoPacket

Tags: go, gsm, gopacket, rtl-sdr

I tried this code (below) for sniffing GSM packet with rtl-sdr device:

```
import rtl "github.com/jpoirier/gortlsdr"


var buffer = make([]uint8, rtl.DefaultBufLength)
for{
     rtl.ReadSync(buffer, rtl.DefaultBufLength)
     fmt.Println(string(buffer))
}
```

now i have some unusable bytes in `buffer`

is it possible parse this bytes by gopacket or something else?

I've used for example [Github](https://github.com/jpoirier/gortlsdr/blob/master/example.go)